# Task Scheduler , run task when .exe from a determined ParentProcessName closes

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .bat that opens two .exes:

```
explorer programA.exe
explorer programB.exe
```

Lets forget about ProgramB.exe and focus on the A.exe

The ProgramA.exe create 3 child process that doesnt close when ProgramA.exe closes, so I'm trying to make a task which kills programA.exe's child process. Its behaviour is like this:

**ProgramA.exe** ,which has a **ParentProcessName=explorer.exe**, executes again or another instance of ***ProgramA.exe*** with ***ParentProcessName=ProgramA.exe***, and then kills the first **programA.exe** (which had **ParentProcessName=explorer.exe**)

My task trigger is like this:

```
  <QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
     *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]] 
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='C:\ProgramA.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Which kills ProgramA's child process when the first instance is killed (**ParentProcessName=explorer.exe**), but those child process are required for it to run properly when its ran again with ***ParentProcessName=ProgramA.exe***

I tried to change the trigger to:

```
*[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='C:\ProgramA.exe') and (ParentProcessName='C:\ProgramA.exe')]]
```

But it isnt the correct synthax.

**TL;DR:** I want to run a task only when an .exe with a ParentProcessName='C:\ProgramA.exe' is closed/terminated/ended

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983112/windows-task-scheduler-how-trigger-task-then-program-has-closed

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to combine all into one .bat file. For example:

```
net start <anApp Service>
"C:\Program Files\<folder>\<anApp.exe>"
net stop <anApp Service>
kill <childProccessA.exe>
kill <childProccessB.exe>
rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
pause
```

This is similar to code I use to:

- Start a service that an application needs, but which I do not want running continuously. Until the service starts, the next line is not executed.
- Run the application. Execution of the batch file halts *until the application exit*s.
- Then the service is stopped.
- *After* the service stops, child processes are terminated (with extreme prejudice ;-).
- A beep sounds to announce completion, and the CMD prompt is left showing with *pause*, to assure that all succeeded.

This is a bit more involved than your question, since others might find the Service and announcement useful, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but it isnt a service. Its oculus client .exe

Comment: @kraudez, yes, as stated, starting and stopping the service are extras you do not need. Just leave out those two lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Still wondering if what Im asking is possible, since it would be "cleaner".